# Изменить последовательность в Grid view

Tags: javascript, css, grid, gridview, css-grid

С сервера приходит список айтемов:

```
<ul class="list">
  <li class="item">Select All</li>
  <li class="item">Civil Id</li>
  <li class="item">Salary Certificate</li>
  <li class="item">Salary Continuity Certificate</li>
  <li class="item">Birth Certificate</li>
  <li class="item">Residency Certificate</li>
  <li class="item">Proof of Employment</li>
  <li class="item">Card Bin</li>
</ul>
```

Айтемы должны располагаться в три колонки, как на рисунке.
[image: Как должны располагаться айтемы]

Я применил Grid view,

```
.list{
    list-style: none;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: auto auto auto;
}
```

однако их последовательность другая в таком расположении и выглядит сейчас вот так [image: Как получилось]

Подскажите, как я могу перевернуть их расположение на grid view?

[image: Вот как надо изменить последовательность на сетке]

Answer (score 0):

Пример 1

```css
.list{
    column-count: 3;
}
```

```html
<ol class="list">
  <li class="item">Select All</li>
  <li class="item">Civil Id</li>
  <li class="item">Salary Certificate</li>
  <li class="item">Salary Continuity Certificate</li>
  <li class="item">Birth Certificate</li>
  <li class="item">Residency Certificate</li>
  <li class="item">Proof of Employment</li>
  <li class="item">Card Bin</li>
</ol>
```

Пример 2

```css
.list {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  grid-auto-flow: column;
}
```

```html
<ol class="list">
  <li class="item">Select All</li>
  <li class="item">Civil Id</li>
  <li class="item">Salary Certificate</li>
  <li class="item">Salary Continuity Certificate</li>
  <li class="item">Birth Certificate</li>
  <li class="item">Residency Certificate</li>
  <li class="item">Proof of Employment</li>
  <li class="item">Card Bin</li>
</ol>
```

Comment: Спасибо, Оставил grid view и воспользовался вторым вариантом. А может вы подскажите, как лучше заимплементить стиль блока с двумя чекбоксами (BIN Number и Imal Code), которые отдельно от этого списка приходят и должны располагаться сразу под Card Bin? Абсолютным позиционированием?